# Multi-armed bandit algorithm for finding the best performing bandit in the least amount of trials

Tags: posterior, multiarmed-bandit

I'm wondering if there's an algorithm that minimizes the expected posterior loss for the best performing bandit where regret is calculated as the number of trials to achieve a threshold for posterior loss.

Example: Let's say we run an AB test to compare click rates for 3 different creatives. For each user, we can decide which creative she will get. Since we are just pretending this is a real-world scenario, we don't gain anything from the click - but we have to pay for each impression the same. Is there a way (an algorithm) to find which creative performs the best in the least amount of impression (trials)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is named **Best Arm Identification**. In this setting, you have no notion of regret but you just aim at identifying the best arm as fast as possible (say in $\tau$ steps) and with a probability at least equal to $1-\delta$, for $\delta\in(0,1)$.

There are many algorithms that have been proposed to solve this problem. A provably (asymptotically for $\delta \to 0$) optimal algorithm is proposed by [Garivier and Kaufmann](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04589), but there are plenty of other algorithms (see [Audibert et al.](http://certis.enpc.fr/%7Eaudibert/Mes%20articles/COLT10.pdf) or [Jamieson et al.](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Ejamieson/resources/bestArmSurvey.pdf)).